# Restoration with auto route in flutter

Tags: flutter

currently, I am not able to restore data when I am changing routes.

how can we restore data using autoroute?

I am unable to find any resources related to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keys https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

```
class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {

    ProductPage({Key key, this.product}) : super(key: key);
    ...
```

call it with a fixed key to reuse the widget `key: Key('ProductPage_${product.id}')` or `key: UniqueKey()` if you want it to be created again every time.